# Can you assign a companion to a siege weapon in a battle?

Tags: mount-and-blade-bannerlord

I have an Engineer in my party, I'd like her to get some relevant experience by using ballistas/mangonels during defensive sieges and rams/towers during offensive ones. But I haven't found a clean way to do that in the UI. I can assign her to a formation and then try to place that formation near a siege weapon but it doesn't really seem to work properly and other random troops end up using the siege weapon instead.

Comment: I have not found this possibility myself yet and think it is not implemented as of now, but agree, that it would be very helpful!